# Forcing browsers to ignore whitespace in HTML code?

Tags: html, css, firefox, whitespace

Recently I have been having issues with Firefox compatibility, I was working on a website on chrome and when I tested it out on Firefox my divs got messed up. So after trying to figure out what the issue was, I came upon a thread about my issue! Apparently, Firefox recognizes the whitespaces in my HTML code and spaces out my divs accordingly. So, is there a way to make Firefox ignore the whitespace in my code? I don't really mind dealing with all my divs on one line but it would be much easier to organize if I could space out my code. Also, if this is possible, what are the downsides, if any?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402672/css-width-wierdness-in-chrome-and-firefox-with-pure-css) is the thread I was talking about. Thanks Drkawashima!

Comment: Why does it matter if it recognizes white space? I've never had a problem with firefox and I've made like 30 sites. Should add some code and a fiddle or something so we can see the problem.

Comment: Suppressing rendering of all whitespaces would lead to terrible results! Just think of text passages with the whitespaces removed... As you can read in that thread the effect only occurs if you use inline rendering. In that case one actually would _expect_ the whitespaces to get rendered.

Comment: The problem is when there is something like `/li><li` vs `/li>\n<li` (and I believe it only affects inline-block..). The 'solution' is to nested the closing and open tags together and put the newlines (or other spaces) elsewhere, even if it doesn't look the cleanest in code.

Comment: If the elements display is set to **inline** or **inline-block** then there will indeed be a space character displayed between elements. If you want to remove it, set the display of the elements to be **block** and float them to the left.

Comment: Probable duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `font-size` of the divs to `0` and the `font-size` for every element inside the divs to `1rem`:

```
div {
    font-size: 0;
}

div > * {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```